# html button group dropdown not working with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, cs50

I'm making a webpage for the web track of cs50 and I was hoping to have options to go to the next/previous page and have a dropdown menu with all of the pages in between, but with bootstrap's code the dropdown menu just doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        hello, homepage
        <div class="pageselector">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
                <button type="btn" class="btn btn-light" disabled>&lt;-</button>

                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" active disabled href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button onclick="window.location.href='page2.html';" type="btn" class="btn btn-secondary">-></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include only css boostrap file, you get only styled components and some basic animations, like the ones that occur on hover.

However, to have more complex interactions like **expanding dropdown** you need to also append JavaScript files at the end of your body tag (so that they are loaded when all elements on the page are loaded).

Here is the fixed example. I've only added needed JavaScript files.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  hello, homepage
  <div class="pageselector">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
      <button type="btn" class="btn btn-light" disabled>&lt;-</button>

      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" active disabled href="#">Dropdown link</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onclick="window.location.href='page2.html';" type="btn" class="btn btn-secondary">-></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the files that I have included are

```html
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: How do you know when you have to do that and what files you need?

Comment: Well, I've read the introduction page of Bootstrap here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ where it says "Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function". And the files I've extracted in my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap js link for dropdown and other js interactions.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Use script just before body tag close.